# ¿como puedo saber cuantos registros tiene una tabla en ruby?

Tags: ruby

Tengo una tabla que tiene mas de 20 millones de registros, pero necesito saber el número exacto de registros, con *count*, `total = Transacciones.count` se tarda aproximadamente 20 segundos en darme la respuesta, existe otra forma para saber con un comando este dato?

Comment: 20 millones de registros para un `count` simple no debería tardar tanto, depende mucho de las capacidades del equipo/servidor, pero incluso 1 segundo (de ejecución en la BD) sería mucho tiempo. ¿Estás utilizando alguna condición adicional (i.e. con `where`)? ¿Qué BD es? ¿Estás seguro que el tiempo es de ejecución en la BD?, ¿si ejecutas `Transacciones.count` en la consola tarda el mismo tiempo?

Comment: De hecho a nivel de consola se tarda mucho mas, mi PC es una PC personal y viejita, estoy usando postgresl, lo de lteimpo de ejecución en la BD, no lo tengo claro, lo estoy midiendo al ojo por ciento a nivel de tiempo de respuesta con mi reloj.

Comment: Al ejecutar `Transacciones.count` en consola te muestra la sentencia _SQL_ que se ejecutó junto con el tiempo (algo similar a esto: `(1234.5ms) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM transacciones`); ¿te muestra que efectivamente se esté ejecutando un `COUNT(*)` sin condiciones? Compara ese tiempo con el de ejecutar la misma sentencia que genera directamente en la BD. Si el tiempo es igual, posiblemente deberías revisar la configuración de Postgres, aunque lo más seguro es que estés limitado por las capacidades del equipo donde está tu aplicación.

Comment: Esta es la salida de la consola
irb(main):002:0> Transaccion.count
   (46428.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "transacciones"
=> 18903143
irb(main):003:0>
YO pienso igual que tu, que la limitación es por el equipo.

Comment: Puedes probar a usar reltuples, que da un valor estimado, y comprobar resultados. Estos enlacen podrían ayudarte: http://mistrucosinformaticos.blogspot.com/2016/10/contar-cantidad-de-registros-en-todas.html http://mistrucosinformaticos.blogspot.com/2015/07/optimizacion-postgressql.html Salud